# play send chunked data as one response

Tags: http, playframework

I want get multi response in one connection, I use the play framework sample code

```
def index = Action {
  Ok.chunked(
    Enumerator("kiki", "foo", "bar").andThen(Enumerator.eof)
  )
}
```

the doc show the result like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

4
kiki
3
foo
3
bar
0
```

but I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Request-Time: 1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2015 03:42:31 GMT

kikifoobar
```

**UPDATE**
I use the Paw and chrome 43 to test this

Comment: Do you access the WebApp directly or via a proxy? How did you make the request? (Browser, JavaScript, curl, something else?)

Comment: Maybe Play sends it all in one chunk because "kiki", "foo", "bar" is just too small to get chunked? You could try bigger chunks (longer text).

Comment: @Peanut I use the browser direct, the chrome version is 43

Comment: @Kris js will give me some ids ,and I need get data form the remote by ids,I need send one response for one record

Comment: What you get is cleared chunked because you can see 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' in the header. I think what you get is correct. Your browser just shows you the the response's content decoded. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Example.

Comment: Yes, it works when the response size is very lager, but I my response is less than that, Is there anyway to configure the chunk size ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in chrome. It was reported (and more or less confirmed) as an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=chunked&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=156023).

Note: This only seems to happen when you use "text/plain" as content type. You might want to try another content type or add an additional header: `'x-content-type-options':'nosniff'` as suggested on the issue tracker.